# SignalR start pending

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm working on chat plugn within my ASP.NET MVC application.

Everything works as expected when there are only two users (different browsers). When third user logs in, his SignalR start request is pending, and other users can not use application anymore.

It seems that SignalR allows only two users to connect.

OnConnected method in hub is never called for third user.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you're running your Application on IIS so the default connection limit is 5000. I would assume it is a logical error in your application like a Thread-Unsafe operation which results in a unhandled lock or smth. Could u show some code of the connection on server and client side?

Comment: I have tried couple of solutions, pure SignalR from tutorials, ChatJS, but all approaches do not work

Comment: Could u please provide some code? Everything else is unfortunately only a glance into the marble. Occurs the problem on all browsers or maybe some of your chrome extension is blocking anything? Do you use SSL? Which ASP.NET Version, which SignalR? Give us more information to help you.

Comment: On Windows Home IIS is limited to 3 concurrent connections - http://serverfault.com/a/800518/147942.