# SignalR pending start connection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr

I'm implementing the SignalR library to use websocket in a kind of 'queue', in a ASP.NET MVC Application.

Everything works as expected when there are only two users. When a third one logs in (I mean, I open a new tab), his SignalR start request is pending, and other users can not use application anymore.

It's happening with all browsers: if I open 3 Chrome tabs, or 3 Firefox, or 2 Chrome or 1 Firefox, or 2 Firefox and 1 Chrome.. it's pending forever.

[image]

My code is the same as the one provided for SignalR tutorials: "Getting Started with SignalR 2 and MVC 5".

Could anyone solve this? I'm starting to think that is an IIS limitation, but I'm not 100% sure. I'm using the last SignalR version (2.3.0), 4.6.1 ASP version (I already enabled WebSockets in the IIS configuration).

I've found a similar question ([SignalR start pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042642/signalr-start-pending/)) but it doesn't seem to give an answer.

JavaScript (client) code:

```
 var attendHub = $.connection.attendHub;

    // Create a function that the hub can call back
    attendHub.client.reloadGrid = function (sr) {
        // Business logic
        }
    };

    $.connection.hub.start();
```

Server Hub (C#) code:

```
public class AttendHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AttendHub>();

    public static void RefreshAttendList(int branchId)
    {
        // Business logic
        ///...
        hubContext.Clients.All.ReloadGrid(sr);
    }
}
```

And I'm calling the RefreshAttendList method from a controller, executing this line:

```
AttendHub.RefreshAttendList(AppInfo.ActiveUser.BranchId);
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out that it was a Local IIS limitation, because I changed the configuration to use IIS Express instead of Local, and it's working like a charm!

Hope this helps to anyone with the same issue!